# HTML5 postMessage returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, postmessage

I am trying to do cross-domain communication using postMessage between a page (on example1.com) and an iframe on the same page that is on example2.com

When the iframe is done loading, it sends a postMessage to the parent page using the following command:

**parent.postMessage('hello parent', 'http://example1.com'); //this command works**

In the event handler for postMessage in the parent page (on example1.com), I send a response back to the child page (example2.com) using the following function:

```
//this function is defined in example1.com:

function receiveMessage(event){

    if (event.origin == "http://example2.com"){

        console.log('Message Received from iframe'); //this line works

        event.source.postMessage('hello to you too', event.origin); //this line does not work

    }

}
```

For some reason, the event handler for postMessage in the iframe is not triggered.

```
//this function is defined in example2.com

function receiveMessage(event){

    if (event.origin == "http://example1.com"){ // I even tried removing this check to no avail

        console.log('Message Received from parent'); //this line works

    }

}
```

When the parent tries to send a message to the iframe it simply returns undefined.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

I tried changing the following line in example1.com's receiveMessage event:

**event.source.postMessage('hello to you too', event.origin);**

to this:

**event.source.postMessage('hello to you too', 'http://example2.com');**

But I get this following error:

**Unable to post message to http://example2.com. Recipient has origin http://example1.com**

Why is event.origin evaluating to http://example1.com when it is receiving a message from example2.com?

example1.com is trying to send itself a postMessage. This ought to be the source of the error

Comment: 1) Browser? 2) What does 'parent' evaluate to?

Comment: You say the "message received from parent" works - then doesn't the non-working line in fact work?

Comment: 1) Chrome v22.0.1229.94. 2) parent evalutes to Window in the console, i.e. example1.com

Comment: What happens if you use `'*'` instead of `event.origin`?

Comment: @pimvdb yea ur right, the line is executed but it does not trigger the message event in the iframe for some reason.

Comment: @robertc i tried '*' as you said, it still returns undefined

Comment: But that line is inside the iframe event handler, isn't it? I tried a very basic demo of your scenario and it seems to work fine - the iframe sends something, the parent notices and sends back, and the iframe obtains the message.

Comment: i use this in the iframe to attach the event handler: window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes postMessage can be very unclear in which frame sends and which one receives. For this reason I created a little script to help unravel communication between frames.

Add the following snippet to your page and watch your console to see what happens. Make sure you add it to your page before the inter frame communication with postMessage begins.

```
  var listener = function (e) {
    console.log('Caught ', e.type, ' event from ', e.source.self, ' to ', e.target, ' origin ', e.origin, ' with data ', e.data, '. Full details: ', e);
  };

  function addToFrame(el) {
    var frames = el.querySelectorAll('iframe'), ifrm = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
      frames[i].contentWindow.addEventListener("message", listener, true);
      ifrm += addToFrame(frames[i].contentWindow.document);
    }
    return i + ifrm;
  }

  window.addEventListener("message", listener, true);
  var c = addToFrame(document);
  console.log('Recursively added listener to main window and', c, 'frames');
```

In your console it clearly states which frame sends what to which other frame.
For more details, please see my blog post I've prepared for you on [my site](http://elgervanboxtel.nl/site/blog/inspect-postmessage-events).

I hope this will help figuring out the iframe communication ;-)

p.s. If this does not help, please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your problem. This will make it easier for us to understand the problem you're having...

Comment: Very useful code, thanks. I didn't realize I needed to attach the event listener to the iframe itself, your code helped me realize that.

Answer (score 0):

In my **Vue** project, i got same result as you, and finally i changed my origins to another host like `127.0.0.10` and then i got data object

here is my code

**first origin : 127.0.0.10:8000**

```js
function sendMessage() {
  document
    .getElementById('frame')
    .contentWindow
    .postMessage('Hello world!', '*');
}
```

```html
<iframe class="d-none" src="http://127.0.0.20:8080/login" onload="sendMessage()" id="frame"></iframe>
```

**second origin : 127.0.0.10:8000**

```js
window.addEventListener(
  "message",
  function (event) {
      if (event.origin.indexOf('127.0.0.10:8000') > 0)
      {
          console.log(event.data);
      }
  }
);
```